# OWL 2 QL axioms in simple language

Tags: owl, ontology, description-logic

I am new to ontology axioms and DL Syntax and trying to understand what exactly the axioms in the image mean. I have also given the reference from where I took the image [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3102254.3102277). Kindly help me to understand these axioms.
[image: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3102254.3102277]

Comment: those are all subclass axioms. some with existential restrictions (`owl:someValuesFrom`), some with additionally inverse relations (`owl:inverse`) in subclass or superclass position. But honestly, even the Wikipedia article would explain the meaning of those symbols: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_logic

Comment: The `∃r` concept constructor (without subsequent `.c`) is an abbreviation for `∃r.⊤`, where `⊤` is an universal concept aka `owl:Thing`. The `C` near `⊑` means that this is a concept inclusion (and not e.g. role inclusion).

Comment: @UninformedUser  If i understood it correctly isn't the 3-8 axioms are domain axioms?

Comment: they are still subclass axioms in DL syntax. and yes, for 3-5 the property domain is basically the idea behind those axioms. 6-8 as well but this is for the inverse of the properties

Comment: @UninformedUser One thing that is confusing for me is the existential quantifier on the left side of axiom 4,5,7,8. so, how can I interpret it as a range axiom because I thought they could be GCI (maybe i am wrong). could you kindly give me example in simple English a possible use case that can be used for 4,5,7,8 axiom? Like for 3rd axiom i can say "worksFor" has domain "organization".

Comment: it's not a range axiom. Any axiom with an existential quantifier (and top concept as role filler which is the case if there is no role filler at all) on the left side can be seen as a domain axiom for `r`.

Comment: Your example is quite confusing. "worksFor" has domain "organization" wouldn't make sense, it might have as range "organization", but the domain should be "person" or "employee" or whatever. A complex domain could be for example for the property `goldMedalsWon` something like `∃ hasProfession.Athlete` which means anything that has a gold medal won has as profession being an athlete of any kind

Comment: @UninformedUser (6) axiom ∃r^-.⊤ ⊑ c is described as a range in this https://aic.ai.wu.ac.at/~polleres/teaching/SemWebTech_2012/20120606lecture6.pdf which makes me wonder 7 and 8 axiom then will be the complex range. I am just trying to understand the notational differences for domain and range.